# Sharer.php and the SSL Migration on Oct 1

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-sharer

How will the Facebook SSL Migration on Oct 1st affect links to http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php ?

Will that link continue to work? Will facebook.com redirect to https or will the link just stop working after October 1st?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's new SSL requirement is for Canvas applications only. Since the link you provided is not a Canvas application (but a part of Facebook's website), it is unaffected by this new requirement.

Facebook has [let users enable HTTPS/SSL on their website](http://www.facebook.com/blog.php?post=486790652130) for over 9 months now. If you have the Secure Browsing setting enabled on your account and you click on http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php, it should automatically redirect you to https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php.

Finally, Facebook's [Share button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) has been deprecated. Their documentation suggests using the [Like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) instead.